# Redirecting a subdomain to subfolder in azure web app

Tags: asp.net, azure, url-rewriting, web-config, azure-web-app-service

I want to rewrite a subdomain to a subfolder in azure webapps

I have this subdomain: `https://portal.domain.com.br` (running in separate server). And I want to use this url: `domain.com.br/portal`.

Here is my web.config:

```
 <rewrite>
  <rules>
   <rule name="Rewrite to portal site" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^portal\/([_0-9a-z-/]+)" ignoreCase="true" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="https://portal.domain.com.br/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true"/>
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

I also tried this:

```
    <rewrite>
  <rules>
   <rule name="Rewrite to portal site" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^portal$" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="https://portal.domain.com.br/{R:0}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

None of those worked. How to proceed?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Could you guide me if you know how it works?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added a CNAME for that subdomain in your DNS. Then use a rewrite rule to redirect requests from `abc.example.com` to `http://example.com/abc`.

Here is an example:

```
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="CName to URL" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(?!www)(.*)\.example\.com$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="http://example.com/{C:1}/{R:0}" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
```

Refer to [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/bd64f444-3711-49de-afb4-a348b0680ebd/map-subdomain-to-subfolder?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview).

Comment: I want to do this rewrite only for this subdomain, not for all