# Redirecting subdomain to subdirectory in Azure App Service

Tags: azure, redirect, azure-web-app-service, subdomain

I have website on azure with domain original.domain.com.

I want to create another subdomains and redirect them to subdirectories

```
first.domain.com -> original.domain.com/first
second.domain.com -> original.domain.com/second
```

Comment: Does my solution help you?

Comment: possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52607200/redirecting-a-subdomain-to-subfolder-in-azure-web-app

Answer (score 0):

Considering not sure about the meaning of your subdirectories, I created two subdirectories named "article" and "another" under `wwwroot` like the pic below, and put `.aspx` files under the files:
[image]

My suggestion for *redirecting subdomain to subdirectories* is changing your custom **CNAME domain** to **wildcard domain**.

The next thing you need to do is adding this snippet code in `web.config` file (create if this file not exists) :([reference](https://support.discountasp.net/kb/a1539/subdirectory-and-subdomain-pointers-with-url-rewrite.aspx))

```
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <fileExtensions>
          <add fileExtension=".aspx" allowed="true"/>
        </fileExtensions>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="article.domain.com" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^article.domain.com$" />
                        <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^/article/" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="\article" />
                </rule>
        <rule name="another.domain.com" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^another.domain.com$" />
                        <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^/another/" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="\another" />
                </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

Then you can access your subdirectories looks like the pic below:
[image]

**PS:** If I got misunderstanding about the subdirectories, please let me know.